# WebGL webcam texture video recording

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, webcam, unity-webgl

I searched on different forums, on unity forums and stackoverflow but till now didn't get succeeded.
I'm actually trying to record video of webcam texture and save to external path.
Already tried mono.jslib but without success. 
There is a lot of forums for showing webcam and saving screen shoot for mobile and unity standalone builds but not find for webGL.

already check these

- [WebCamTexture, get correct resolution and RATIO](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/773464/webcamtexture-correct-resolution-and-ratio.html?childToView=1148424#answer-1148424)
- [Capture images using device camera](https://praveenlk.wordpress.com/2014/09/21/capture-images-using-device-camera/)

There is more forums but stackoverflow only allow me only 2 links to share.

Guys is there any way to capture or record video/stream of webcam from webGL build. ??

Any code of web java script that we call from mono class ??

Thanks in advance.

only C# code is here by using system.IO but could't save files.

```
// Geting deices cameras 
var devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
    var backCamName = "";
    if(devices.Length > 0) backCamName = devices[0].name;
    for(int i = 0; i < devices.Length; i++) {
        Debug.Log("Device:" + devices[i].name + "IS FRONT FACING:" + devices[i].isFrontFacing);
        if(!devices[i].isFrontFacing) {
            backCamName = devices[i].name;
        }
    }

    CameraTexture = new WebCamTexture(backCamName, 256, 256, 30);
    CameraTexture.Play();
    var renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderer.material.mainTexture = CameraTexture;


    // use this code for to save texture. 

    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(256, 256, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
    //Save the image to the Texture2D
    texture.SetPixels(CameraTexture.GetPixels());
    texture.Apply();
    CentralVariables.saveTexture = texture;
    CentralVariables.SaveToFile ();
```

I was trying to save file by above code but file system not works in webGL.